# Python API to extract closest dated SAR data

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I have a google earth engine javascript code to detect water pixel in the closest date SAR imagery. Link of the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0a35eea49123a5390b822bac7afc1b0c. I can run the code in GEE and returning exactly what I required (1 if the location is above water and 0 when it above land).

I have tried to develop the following code which is returning the dictionary, not the single expected output.

```
import ee, datetime
ee.Initialize()
waterThresh = -16;
angle_threshold_1 = ee.Number(45.4);
angle_threshold_2 = ee.Number(31.66);

class AltimeterExtraction(object):
    def __init__(self, locationfile = './Bin/Location_Data.txt'):
        filecontent = open(locationfile, 'r')
        content = csv.DictReader(filecontent, delimiter='\t')

   def watertestpoint(self, lat=10.55587,lon=89.89789, date1='2019-04-05'):
        lat = ee.Number(lat)
        lon = ee.Number(lon)
        datep = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%Y-%m-%d")
        date2 = datep + datetime.timedelta(days = -10)

        point = ee.Geometry.Point([lon,lat])

        S1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD').filterBounds(point).filterDate(date2, date1)
        S1 = S1.map(self.maskByAngle)
        S1 = S1.select('VV').median().rename('VV')
        S1 = S1.focal_median(50,'circle','meters').rename('VV')
        WaterMask = S1.lt(waterThresh)
        flag = WaterMask.reduceRegion(**{
            'reducer': ee.Reducer.mean(),
            'geometry': point,
            'scale': 10
        });

        return flag.get('VV')

    def maskByAngle(self, img):
        I = ee.Image(img)
        angle = I.select('angle')
        mask1 = angle.lt(angle_threshold_1)
        mask2 = angle.gt(angle_threshold_2)
        I = I.updateMask(mask1)
        return I.updateMask(mask2)


P = AltimeterExtraction()
x= P.watertestpoint()
print x
```

Are there any ways to get the single value instead of the dictionary from python? I need the binary output (0 or 1) from the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `.getInfo()` while printing to get the actual value from that point. Earth Engine process all of the data on the server side so you have to explicitly call `.getInfo()` to return the information.

Here is an example I used:

```
P = AltimeterExtraction() 
x= P.watertestpoint(lat=20.5564,lon=94.818,date1='2019-03-30') 
print(x.getInfo())
```

Comment: Thanks, but my code was fine. The problem was during some lat-lon where data was not available.